# "All but convinced" as a way of saying that one is, in fact, convinced?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“All but” idiom has two meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9967/all-but-idiom-has-two-meanings)

It seems kind of counterintuitive, but saying that:

> I'm all but convinced that ponies eat leprechauns.

means

> I'm **absolutely** convinced that ponies eat leprechauns.

It seems that this is backwards; it would seem to mean "I'm everything except convinced that ponies eat leprechauns," meaning that I'm not convinced, but open to the possibility.

What does this "all but *(adjective)*" conjunction mean?

Comment: Why do you think *"all but convinced"* means the same as *"absolutely convinced"?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*[All but](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_but) convinced* means you are on the verge of being convinced, not that you are absolutely convinced.  *Almost* is nearly synonymous with *all but*, but it sounds more phlegmatic.  *Very nearly* is the definition given by Wiktionary (click the above link).

*All but* does not mean *everything except*; see it more as *everything up to* (i.e. **All** the way up to a state of convincedness, **but** not quite there).

Comment: +1, though I want to emphasize that "almost" and "all but" are not really that synonymous. An "almost convinced" person is quite a bit more skeptical than an "all but convinced" person. If you are all but convinced, you don't really need any more convincing; if you are almost convinced, however, you do.

Comment: Maybe *phlegmatic* wasn't the right choice of word.  There, I made the wording a little stronger.

Comment: I may be flummoxed; does this answer discord with english.stackexchange.com/a/9971/50720?

Comment: @LePressentiment No; does it look that way?

Answer (score 4):

When followed by an adjective, **all but** is an idiom and it means **almost**. In your example therefore, it means *I am almost convinced that...*

Perhaps you are confusing it with its other use. Consider: *All but one of the cars were damaged.* In this sentence, **all but** is followed by **one** which functions as a noun, and it means *with one exception*.

Comment: Great point about an adjective!