# Which one is more appropriate?

Tags: sentence

My friend said this to me when I suggested a place to go, "Anywhere but there". I asked my friend if he meant "Anywhere but not there", and he said both are equivalent. Is this true or is one of them more appropriate?

Comment: See also a question about ["all but"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194750/can-you-clarify-usage-of-all-but) and question(s) linked from that one.

Answer (score 1):

'But' in this context means the same as 'except'. Your friend meant that he would rather go anywhere else than the place you had suggested.