# "However, this book is anything but" meaning

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

What's the structure and meaning of this sentence in the following text:

> A friend lent this to me before I headed over to Italy and France this summer. I was a bit skeptical at first as he's heavily into the technical aspects of architecture. *However, this book is anything but*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“nothing but” vs. “anything but” vs. “everything but”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8061/nothing-but-vs-anything-but-vs-everything-but).

Comment: Per my comment under Third Idiot's answer, this extract is poor quality writing. I would not advise it be used by anyone wishing to enhance their understanding of the English language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This [object] is anything but" is another way of saying "This is nothing like what I had initially thought about .. [that object]"

So the author thought the book given by his friend would not be to his liking, as the donor was "*heavily into the technical aspects of architecture*" and he was pleasantly surprised when that was not the case. The book was not as bad as he thought.

Answer (score 4):

> ...at first as he's heavily into the **technical aspects of architecture.** However, this book is anything but.

The sentence you italicized is saying the books is anything but "heavily into technical aspects of architecture.

Comment: Idiot: I agree absolutely with your parsing there. However I do feel the original text is somewhat less than sparkling prose. First we have a **friend** who's *heavily into...*, which is perfectly valid, although a bit 'slangy'. But then that's juxtaposed with a **book** being *heavily into...*, which quite frankly is a metaphor too far for me in this context. Books are inanimate - they can't really be *into* anything, let alone *heavily*.